# how do you communicate with containerized apis

Tags: docker, nginx, fastapi

i'm a bit hazy about the process...

i have a ufw setup that only allows 443 and 80..which goes straight to the webserver (nginx container)

that handles any requests to my website.

i also have a fastapi container that connects to a postgres container by looking at the digitalocean ip address + the postgres container port.

it's inside the droplet, so it can communicate with other containers that share the same ip?  in any case..it works. even though i dont understand how, since it's not configured in nginx...

but what is the exact process when i try to request something from the fastapi container?

if i try to fetch some json from within my containerized app..using the droplet ip + the fastapi port number leads it to timing out..

is there a way to connect to the fastapi container in the same way i can connect to the postgres container?

thanks

Comment: Containers can communicate with each other using the container name if they're on the same docker network.  That way you could rely on the static container names instead of the IP addresses.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of theory:

You have a droplet which has its own ports, they can be closed or opened in the internet. Droplet is a host of docker. Every docker container has it's own ports which are closed for host and another containers by default and you should open them with `network` or `expose` (I'll describe it).

---

It's unclear if your fastApi container and postgres container are on the same droplet or not so I describe the common situation.

Small sumarize of text bellow:

- To config containers to communicate with each other, use docker networks.

  You can run DB with: `docker run --network <networkName> --network-alias <aliasName> <imageName>`

  Your API container: `docker run --network <networkName> <imageName>`

  Then, the app can connect to DB with `<protocol>://<aliasName>:<dbPort>`.
- To allow your host connect to your docker container, you should expose some container's port and map it to some host's port:
  `docker run --expose <exposedPort> --publish <hostPort>:<exposedPort> <imageName>`
- you can expose port while you build the image, hence you don't need to use `--expose` in run command
- to open your port to the internet, your droplet should keep the port opened or you can use nginx and proxy opened port to your `<hostPort>` from point above
- I use simple docker commands as the base to describe the idea, but you can run all containers above with docker compose

*Small security note:* I don't recommend you to open DB's port to the Internet if you don't understand what you do as it's unsecure and can cause security issues in the future.

---

More wide answer with links to docker documentation:

Then, if you have such tools:

- one digitalocean droplet
- fastApi container with your app
- container with some DB

1. You should close all ports except 80 and 443 ports on your droplet due to security reason. It's good practice to open only ports you need to be public. 80 and 443 ports allow users to connect to your server with HTTP/HTTPS.
2. Docker allows containers to communicate with each other with using network bridge. You can read more details here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/

   Why do we need to create the network? While you run docker containers, every of them is isolated and all its ports are hidden. So you can add option `--network <networkName>` for `run` command (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#connect-a-container-to-a-network---network).
   All containers which are connected to the same `network-name` can "communicate" with each other. Also you can use `--network-alias <aliasName>` option to change the name for your container.

   For example:
   I runned mongodb recently, so mongodb is running on port 27017 inside of container by default. I set the alias `mongo` and connect it to some network. So when I run my container with app with the same network, I should connect to DB with url `mongodb://mongo:27017`.
3. Okay, you connected FastApi container to DB container and can make requests to DB. But you wanna see your fastApi app outside the host (droplet). Then, you should open the port. Suppose you run your fastApi app on 8080 port. You should expose this port in container with `--expose` option (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose).

   Just adding `--expose` option with port isn't enought. It just opens port inside your container but your host (droplet) hasn't connection to it. You should map some port of your host to your container's exposed port with `--publish` option (see last link above).
4. In the begining we closed all ports except 80 and 443. You can use Nginx to proxy all requests to your closed port. For example you can proxy all requests from http://ip:80/api to your localhost:8080 to make it work.
5. Optionally. if you have only DB container in your droplet and want to connect to droplet and db. You can expose DB's port and map it to some droplet's port. Then, you can open the droplet's port and connect to it but I don't recomend to make it in such way as it's unsecure. You also can connect to your DB from your API by SSL (at least you should set SSH for it, I think).